# asp.net - Impedir cliques consecutivos em botão

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma aplicação asp.net webform, e estou tendo o seguinte problema.

Em certa parte do sistema, o cliente possui dois botões para navegar entre as edições de uma revista, indo para anterior e próxima. Isso funciona corretamente, só que as vezes o cliente clica várias vezes simultâneas até chegar na edição que deseja, ao invés de esperar carregar uma a uma (justo).

Porém, quando ele faz isso, a cada clique que dá é chamado o evento contido no clique do botão, e é um evento demorado, com consulta no banco e várias indexações.

Eu queria saber se tem uma forma de impedir que isso aconteça. Do cliente poder clicar várias vezes rápido até chegar na edição que deseja, e só aí chamar o evento do botão.

o botão:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProximaEdicao" runat="server" onclick="btnProximaEdicao_Click" OnClientClick="return mudarEdicao('proxima');" Text="Próxima" Height="34px"/>
```

JS:

```
function mudarEdicao(acao) {
        if (!verificarColunas())
            return false;
        else {

            var filtro = $('select[name$="LstFiltros"]').find('option');

            $.each(filtro, function (key, value) {
                var coluna = $(value).val();
                if (coluna.indexOf('Edição') >= 0) {
                    var edicao = coluna.substr(7);
                    var proxEdicao;
                    if (acao == "anterior")
                        proxEdicao = parseInt(edicao) - 1;
                    else
                        proxEdicao = parseInt(edicao) + 1;

                    $('select[name$="LstFiltros"]').find('option[value^="Edição"]').val("Edição:" + proxEdicao);
                    $('select[name$="LstFiltros"]').find('option[value^="Edição"]').text("Edição:" + proxEdicao);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void btnProximaEdicao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < LstFiltros.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (LstFiltros.Items[i].Text.Contains("Edição:"))
        {
            string edicao = LstFiltros.Items[i].Text.Substring(7);

            int proxEdicao = Convert.ToInt32(edicao) + 1;

            LstFiltros.Items.Remove(LstFiltros.Items[i].Text);

            ((List<DocumentoCamposDTO>)this.getParameter("CAMPOS_PESQUISA")).RemoveAll(p => p.TipoIndexacaoCampo.GUID.Equals(Functions.ConvertToGuid(LstGuidCampos.Items[i].Text)));

            LstFiltros.Items.Add("Edição:" + proxEdicao);

            InsereFiltrosPesquisa();
        }
    }

    preencherGridPesquisa();
}
```

muito obrigado.

Comment: Está utilizando um UpdatePanel para atualizar o conteudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode desativar os botão btnProximaEdicao no momento do click;

```
var btnProximaEdicao = document.querySelector('[id$="btnProximaEdicao"]');

function mudarEdicao(acao) {
    if (!verificarColunas())
        return false;
    else {
        btnProximaEdicao.disabled = true; //desativando o btnProximaEdicao
        ... // o resto do escrito permanece como estava.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Caso esteja utilizando um UpdatePanel, você precisa desativar o `btnProximaEdicao` quando a requisição AJAX começar, e voltar a ativar o mesmo quando ela termianar, para tal use o seguinte script:

```
var btnProximaEdicao = document.querySelector('[id$="btnProximaEdicao"]');
var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
pageRequestManager.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    btnProximaEdicao.disabled = true; //desativando o btnProximaEdicao
}
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    btnProximaEdicao.disabled = true; //ativando o btnProximaEdicao
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei dar um disabled, mas quando fiz isso, ele não executou o evento do click. Apenas chamou o JS e parou nisso...

Vou tentar dessa forma, com o pageRequestManager para ver se muda alguma coisa.

Mas por acaso existiria alguma solução que impeça o erro mas permita o cliente dar os vários cliques? Uma forma de só chamar o AJAX se o cliente ficar uns 3 segundos sem clicar, por exemplo?

Comment: Bom, fiz o teste e não deu em nada. Posso ter feito algo errado?

Comment: Tente no lugar de desativar o button, apenas setar uma variável local e testar a mesma no onclick.

Comment: Obrigado, mas não entendi o que quis dizer...

Comment: A sugestão dada não surtiu efeito, pois após o post, a variável continua marcada como true.

Como faço para saber que a página foi atualizada e resetar a variável?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, muito obrigado.

No fim das contas, a primeira sugestão foi a base para eu resolver, só não estava funcionando porque estava colocando no local errado.

Só não pude bloquear o botão porque para de funcionar, mas usei a variável para indicar que já cliquei, então na volta do post zero a variável.